# Swift: perform task once device connected

Tags: swift, api, background-task

I'm looking for the best method to perform an API call once the user's device has reconnected to the internet.

The background is that I am building in offline support for an app which required data to be posted to a specific endpoint. So my idea is that the device will be offline when the data is submitted and then once the device is online, I will then post to the required endpoint.

I've looked into various background tasks but I can't find one with which you can specify that the task be performed as soon as the device is connected to a network. I know that Apple tends to restrict when background tasks can be performed taking into consideration battery life and other variables, so is this just something that cannot be done?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a URLSession using a background URLSessionConfiguration:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: backgroundIdentifier)
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
```

When you use this session, the operation will be performed in the background when possible, even when your app is not running. You can further configure this by setting `isDiscretionary` to true, to avoid sending data on cellular networks, and waiting for the device to be plugged in.

See [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background) for additional information. While it is focused on downloading, the same processes apply for posting.

Comment: Thanks for this. When you say it will be performed when possible, does this mean as soon as possible or just the first time it succeeds on a scheduled operation. I.e. as soon as the device is connected would this be performed ?

Comment: If your app is in the foreground when the transfer could start, and is not marked as discretionary, then it will be started immediately. If your app is in the background, then the transfer is automatically marked as discretionary, so it will likely not start until the device is plugged in and on WiFi (though there aren't promises around this; it could start earlier if your configuration allows it). There is no way to ensure that it starts as soon as a network is available if your app is not also in the foreground at the time.